# sidekiq doesn't pick up the configuration file in the default location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, yaml, sidekiq

Sidekiq failed to start with default configuration file in config/sidekiq.yml.

```
---
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: log/sidekiq.log
```

While running the `bundle exec sidekiq -d` in a rails application root, it reports error:

```
You really should set a logfile if you're going to daemonize.
/home/canoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:141:in `daemonize'
/home/canoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:39:in `parse'
/home/canoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/canoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/canoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

However, this should work according to the [wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options) since the config file is in the default path.

What's wrong here?

Comment: would you please show the backtrace .

Comment: answered, you can test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. this was a bug in `2.17.2` , use `2.17.7` version. That's all.